# JSF support in Eclipse Mars.2

Tags: eclipse, jsf, eclipse-plugin, jsf-2.2

I found this page for description how to convert html page into JSF page:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs92/studio33/JSF/ConvertingHTMLtoJSF.html

But I can't find this option into Eclipse Mars.2. Do I need to install some additional plugin?

Comment: The advantage of using a plugin like this for conversion is kind of low... very low... Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 0):

You present the link for documentation of BEA workshop. Convert html to jsf function is part of it. You have to install this tools 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13226_01/workshop/docs92/studio33/Installation/InstallationInstructions.html